# How do you launch the JavaScript debugger in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

When using Google Chrome, I want to debug some JavaScript code. How can I do that?

Comment: See [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) at Webmasters.SE

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: You might also find this useful: [How-to-terminate-script-execution-when-debugging-in-Google-Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134723/how-to-terminate-script-execution-when-debugging-in-google-chrome/29392465#29392465)

Answer (score 320, accepted):

Windows: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd> OR F12

Mac: <kbd>⌥</kbd>-<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd>

Also available through the wrench menu (Tools > JavaScript Console):

[image: JavaScript Console Menu]

Comment: I think the shortcut has since changed to CTRL-SHIFT-J.

Comment: or Cmd-Shift-J for Macs. God I love this `<kbd>` tag. Too bad I can't use it in comments.

Comment: The Mac shortcut seems to actually be `Alt-Cmd-J` on the latest Chrome build.

Comment: looking at this question makes me understand how much my javascript skills improved from novice levels to quite decent standards

Answer (score 425):

Try adding this to your source:

```
debugger;
```

It works in most, if not all browsers. Just place it somewhere in your code, and it will act like a breakpoint.

Comment: It's hard to find what this command is called if you've forgotten it!

Comment: It's also tough to google for reasons why this doesn't always work.  Are there limitations on this?

Comment: You need to have Chrome Developer Tools open for this to work (hit F12 on Windwos/Linux, don't know the key on a Mac, or just inspect an element). If you have Developer Tools open, an extra bit of awesomeness is that you can click and hold the Refresh button to clear the cache.

Comment: It's also super awful if you accidentally leave this in a non widely tested codepath, only to have your users complain about the whole webpage pausing when clicking something. Not that this happened to me :p (we now have a lint to stop debugger statements being merged into develop).

Comment: @CallumRogers Only if your users use your site with the Developer Tools open, though.

Comment: @JoshM. Please note that leaving this in Production code is very bad as it causes issues in certain versions of IE even for users who don't have dev tools open.

Comment: Thanks, does anyone know how to enable the console directly under the debugger pane? Sometimes it appears, but other times not, and I must constantly switch between the "Console" tab and the "Sources" tab where the debugger is paused. EDIT: found out how, simply press Escape in Sources tab :) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537738/chrome-developer-tools-view-console-and-sources-views-in-separate-views-vertica)

Answer (score 58):

Windows and Linux:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> keys to open Developer Tools

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to open Developer Tools and bring focus to the Console.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to toggle Inspect Element mode.

Mac:

<kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> keys to open Developer Tools

<kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to open Developer Tools and bring focus to the Console.

<kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to toggle Inspect Element mode.

[Source](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)

[Other shortcuts](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/shortcuts)

Comment: On mac, the shorcut to toggle inspect element mode is  shift ⌘ C (Shift - Command - C)

Answer (score 15):

Press the <kbd>F12</kbd> function key in the Chrome browser to launch the JavaScript debugger and then click "Scripts".

Choose the JavaScript file on top and place the breakpoint to the debugger for the JavaScript code.

Comment: F12 does not seem to open the debugger on my Windows 7 system with Chrome 23.0.1246.0 dev-m.

Comment: +1 for F12, it also works for IE, FF, Edge. No need to learn Emacs like key combinations. Except for Mac.

Answer (score 11):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> opens Developer Tools.

Answer (score 6):

In Chrome 8.0.552 on a Mac, you can find this under menu *View*/*Developer*/*JavaScript Console* ... or you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

Answer (score 6):

Here, you can find the shortcuts to access the developer tools.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/shortcuts

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> opens the Developer tool window. From bottom-left second image (that looks like the following) will open/hide the console for you:

[image: Show Console]

Answer (score 2):

To open the dedicated ‘Console’ panel, either:

- Use the keyboard shortcuts

  - On Windows and Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>
  - On Mac: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>
- Select the Chrome Menu icon, menu -> *More Tools* -> *JavaScript Console*. Or if the Chrome Developer Tools are already open, `press` the ‘Console’ tab.

Please refer [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)

Answer (score 2):

Now google chrome has introduce new feature. By Using this feature You can edit you code in chrome browse. (Permanent change on code location)

For that Press F12 --> Source Tab -- (right side) --> File System - in that please select your location of code. and then chrome browser
will ask you permission and after that code will be sink with green color. and you can modify your code and it will also reflect on you code location (It means it will Permanent  change)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For Mac users, go to Google Chrome --> menu *View* --> *Developer* --> *JavaScript Console*.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way I have found to get to the javascript debugger is by running this:

`chrome://inspect`

Answer (score 0):

**F12** 
opens the developer panel

**CTRL + SHIFT + C** 
Will open the hover-to-inspect tool where it highlights elements as you hover and you can click to show it in the elements tab.

**CTRL + SHIFT + I**
Opens the developer panel with console tab

**RIGHT-CLICK > Inspect**
Right click any element, and click "inspect" to select it in the Elements tab of the Developer panel.

**ESC**
If you right-click and inspect element or similar and end up in the "Elements" tab looking at the DOM, you can press **ESC** to toggle the console up and down, which can be a nice way to use both.

Answer (score 0):

These are the tools you see

Press the `F12`

[image: developer tools]

Answer (score -5):

From the console in Chrome, you can do `console.log(data_to_be_displayed)`.

Comment: This will not open the console. This will only log to the console.