# Blank page in Chrome & Safari after compiling

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I'm writing a web application in GWT and always worked in Dev Mode. I wanted to check some things in other browsers so I compiled the whole app and opened it in all major browsers. The application shows in Firefox and IE, but not in Chrome and Safari. 
Chrome and Safari just give me a blank page. When I press ctrl + u to view the source, the code is there, but it doesn't to anything.

I already checked the html host page for errors with the W3C validator but there were none.
Any other suggestions?

Comment: Could you provide the html generated by your web application? It might help to dig the problem.

Comment: Could you show the module file (xxx.gwt.xml)?

Comment: Did you check the JavaScript console in Chrome for errors? (View->Developer->JavaScript Console)

Comment: Ok sorry for the late answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it working the following way. When I compile everything and just open the file In chrome or safari it doesn't work and I get following error in the console:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access
>   frame with URL
>   file:///H:/xampp/htdocs/bibliotheek/BibPhp.html
>   from frame with URL
>   file:///H:/xampp/htdocs/bibliotheek/bibphp/66B91B7CC29032C1F497FD7DE63723A5.cache.html.
>   Domains, protocols and ports must
>   match.

But when I transfer everything to my web server it works fine. It has to do something with cross server accessing frames. Here is more about the issue:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31068

Answer (score 0):

You might have a JavaScript error, did you try debugging the JS?

[Google Chrome Javascript Debugger and Content Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895751/google-chrome-javascript-debugger-and-content-scripts)

Comment: I'm using GWT as a plugin in Eclipse so if there is an error in the java code resulting in a error in the javascript code eclipse will let me know, or not?

Comment: I believe that in modern GWT/Eclipse (since Out Of Process Hosted Mode) a log of runtime errors can be seen in the View->Google->Development Mode console.

Comment: I haven't used GWT yet so I don't know what the work flow is like, but I know you write in Java and end up with JavaScript. You didn't give us example to work with in your question, so I'd start by defining the issue so you know for sure what to fix.

Comment: In dev mode there is no problem. No errors in the log screen. It's just a problem when I compile everything. What do you mean with giving an example? I can't give you a specific line of code or something like that...