# Javascript redirect and reset timer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, timer

Newbie to JS. Working with a count down timer and an alert.

Trying to create an alert that pops up after 5 seconds of inactivity and when `Yes` is clicked - you will be redirected to a certain URL. When `Cancel` is clicked, the timer will be reset and you may stay on the page (until the timer runs out, etc, etc).

The code will be used in a Google Extension.

The code I have so far is as follows - I've mad a JS fiddle.  The timer reset doesn't work when 'cancel' is clicked.

If somebody could lend any advice I would be grateful.

http://jsfiddle.net/johnny_s/c7h1qf49/

My `myscript.js`

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = "timer";
div.style.width = "100px";
div.style.height = "100px";
div.style.background = "red";
div.style.color = "white";
div.style.position = "fixed";
div.style.top = "50%";
div.style.left = "50%";
div.innerHTML = "Hello";
document.body.appendChild(div);

var IDLE_TIMEOUT = 5; //seconds
var _idleSecondsTimer = null;
var _idleSecondsCounter = 0;

document.onclick = function () {
    _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
};

document.onmousemove = function () {
    _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
};

document.onkeypress = function () {
    _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
};

_idleSecondsTimer = window.setInterval(CheckIdleTime, 1000);

function CheckIdleTime() {

    _idleSecondsCounter++;

    var oPanel = document.getElementById("timer");

    if (oPanel) oPanel.innerHTML = (IDLE_TIMEOUT - _idleSecondsCounter) + "";

    if (_idleSecondsCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT) {
        window.clearInterval(_idleSecondsTimer);

        if (confirm('You are being redirected due to inactivity - click Cancel for more time, or OK to go to home page?')) {
            //test go to google
            document.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
        } else {
            //reset the timer to 5
        }

    }
}
```

My `manifest.json` looks as follows;

```
{
"update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",

  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Idle Reset",
  "description": "Reset the browser to a single tab pointing at the home page when idle.",
  "version": "1.0.3",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["eventPage.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "idle"
  ],
  "options_page":   "options.html",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["zepto.min.js", "kiosk.js", "myscript.js"],
      "css": [ "reset.css"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How is that code executed? Is it a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)? What happens if you [debug it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895751/google-chrome-javascript-debugger-and-content-scripts)? Post the contents of manifest.json

Comment: What is the name of the file that contains the posted code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from @sdespont I got it working, with a few amendments.

The working code is;

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = "timer";
div.style.display = "none";
div.style.width = "200px";
div.style.height = "200px";
div.style.background = "red";
div.style.color = "white";
div.style.position = "fixed";
div.style.top = "80%";
div.style.left = "50%";
document.body.appendChild(div);

var timeoutID;
var timerID;
var idleTimeout = 5; 
var idleSecondsTimer = null;
var idleSecondsCounter = 0;

function setup() {
    this.addEventListener("mousemove", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("mousedown", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("keypress", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("mousewheel", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("touchmove", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("MSPointerMove", resetTimer, false);

    startTimer();
}
setup();

function startTimer() {
    // wait 2 seconds before calling goInactive
    timeoutID = setTimeout(goInactive, 2000);
}

function resetTimer(e) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    clearTimeout(timerID);    
    goActive();
}

function goInactive() {
    idleSecondsCounter = 0;

    div.style.display = "block";
    div.innerHTML = "Inactivity detected. Redirecting in ...<span id='countdown'>" + (idleTimeout - idleSecondsCounter) + "</span> ...please touch screen to close this message";
    // show a count down here then redirect to google.com

    timerID = setInterval(function(){ 
        idleSecondsCounter++; 

        if(idleSecondsCounter >= 6) {
            clearTimeout(timerID);    
            window.location.href = "http://google.com";
        } else {            
            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = (idleTimeout - idleSecondsCounter);
        }
    }, 1000);    
}

function goActive() {
    div.style.display = "none";
    startTimer();
}
```