# How to debug ember inspector extension(or similar extensions)?

Tags: debugging, ember.js, google-chrome-extension, inspector

I am trying contribute to ember inspector code in google chrome. 
I am lost how to do debugging on dev tool like ember inspector. There guide linke to debug extension on chrome by right click+ inspect popout . However ember inspector is not popout and inspect popout does not work. 
I am having similar issue with debugging RES(Reddit Enhancement Suite).

It would be great if you point a path for me.

Comment: [How to debug chrome devtools panel extension?](//stackoverflow.com/q/27661243)

Comment: Thanks a lot!
For the extension that does not open dev tool(like RES),what can be the way?

Comment: 1. [devtools for the background page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10258029), 2. devtools on a web page to [debug the content script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21734890).