# Cannot debug JavaScript code listed in "content_scripts" of Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

There's a Chrome extension consisting of many .js files and its manifest.json lists some of them inside `content_scripts` section and some of them inside `background` section

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["content/interestingScript.js"
        "match_about_blank": true,
        "all_frames": true
    },
],

"background":
{
    "scripts": ["background/background.js"]
},
```

I switch Chrome into developer mode and add this extension. The extension is fully working as expected. I want a breakpoint set onto some piece of code inside `interestingScript.js` which I surely know is executed during extension operation.

When I get to extension tile at chrome://extensions/?id=longRandomString it says I can inspect the background page and there's a link. I follow the link and get into DevTools and there I get to "Sources" tab. The `background.js` is listed on the left but `interestingScript.js` is not listed there.

I tried to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21734890/57428) and bring up "Content Scripts" tab but the script is not there either. I tried to get to "FileSystem" tab and add the folder where the sources are stored and the script is added but breakpoints are not hit. I tried to add "debugger;" line into that code I'm sure is executing but again nothing happens. I also tried to insert `alert()` calls in that code - they have no effect even after I click "reload" on the extension page (at chrome://extensions/?id=longRandomString)

I don't get it.

How do I get this code debugged in Chrome DevTools? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to open DevTools for the page that the content script is supposed to run on, not for the extension's background page. You should then find it listed in Sources > Content Scripts.

Comment: Yeap, that looks working. `alert()` still has no effect but I don't care. Thank you.

Comment: Modern Chrome won't show alert/prompt /confirm in inactive tabs.