# In AJAX/JavaScript, how is it possible to refer to an undefined variable (anonymous function)?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm following the W3Schools tutorial on AJAX, and it provides an example of using a JavaScript callback function [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_callback) (code pasted below):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlhttp;
function loadXMLDoc(url,cfunc)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc;
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
function myFunction()
{
loadXMLDoc("ajax_info.txt",function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

What confuses me is how this sets `onreadystatechange` to run `cfunc` when triggered, but `cfunc` isn't defined. All of my (admittedly basic) programming experience says this should cause an error because you can't refer to a variable/function/etc. before defining it (or passing it).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5018702/1118357) to another StackOverflow question says `cfunc` is an "anonymous function" defined within another function, but that only confused me more... Am I misunderstanding something fundamental here?

Comment: W3Schools is **the worst place** to begin your journey with JavaScript / AJAX / HTML or anything else. See Mozilla Developer Network instead. And read [w3fools.com](http://w3fools.com)

Comment: Wow, Mozilla Developer Network is a fantastic resource, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, but I would rather say that W3Schools is a terrible resource and anything accurate is way better than W3Schools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cfunc` is assigned a value on this line:

```
function loadXMLDoc(url,cfunc)
```

You pass a function when you call that `cfunc`:

```
loadXMLDoc("ajax_info.txt",function() /* and the next several lines */
```

> "anonymous function" defined within another function, but that only confused me more… Am I misunderstanding something fundamental here?

Functions are just a type of object. You can pass them just like you can pass Arrays, Objects, Numbers and anything else.

Comment: Ah, I see. I mixed up the scope of the function `loadXMLDoc()`. But `cfunc` is only used within that function... Thanks!