# Javascript simple script doesn't execute

Tags: javascript

I've always been hesitant to learn JS since I have to go out of my way to debug the script. The support for such things is poor compared to IDEs for C#/C++ etc.

I'm trying a simple PHP and JS script to retrieve data from my MySQL database, but "onchange" doesn't seem to be triggered:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>

<script type='text/javascript'>

function ShowUser(name)
{
    if(name == "")
    {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Please enter a username to check";
        return;
    }
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "index.php?uName=" + name, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<form>

    <?php
        $data = array();
        if(!empty($_GET['uName']))
        {
            $r = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "pass") or die("Couldn't connect to db");
            mysql_select_db("db", $r) or die ("Couldn't select db");
            $q = mysql_query("select * from users where uName = '{$_GET['uName']}'") or die("Couldn't query table");
            $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
            mysql_close($r);
        }

    ?>

    <input type="text" name="fUName" onchange="ShowUser(this.value);" style="width:125px;">

</form>

<div id="display"><?php print_r($data); ?></div>

</body>

</html>
```

It must be something silly I'm missing. Most of this code was taken from W3schools and put with my own PHP and HTML.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use [IE Dev Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565622(v=vs.85).aspx), [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), or [Chrome debugger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420/how-do-you-launch-the-javascript-debugger-in-google-chrome) to debug your javascript.

Comment: [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), it is your friend.

Comment: @Lee A couple tips, you should declare variables with `var` to avoid polluting the global scope. I'd avoid line-breaks after parentheses in JavaScript, since it can lead to bugs. Try this for example: `var abc = function ()
{
}
(0 === 1);`. (With the line-break after `function ()`.)

Comment: nothing wrong with your javascript onchange trigger. Put alert in your function start. It is working.

Comment: @Matt I understand those concepts. This was supposed to be something quick to test I understand what I've been reading today, before bed!
@Josh, my braces habits come from other languages I know. It's a shame I'll have to change for JS.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Lee Yeah, it's a bit of an odd language, but once you're used to it development can go really fast :).

Comment: @Lee don't change your brace style for JS. I also prefer Allman style braces. Basically the only place they don't work in JS is when you want to return an object literal (this is due to semicolon insertion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the reason your code isn't even being called is because the `onchange` event isn't triggered until after the text input has lost focus (at least, that's what happens in Chrome). So you're probably changing the value of the text box like crazy, but never clicking outside of it, so nothing happens.

Comment: Side note: when you do `onchange="ShowUser(this.value)"`, you're still going to get an error, because `this` in that context refers to `window`, *not* the text box's value.

Comment: Aha! I must be tired.. I never clicked outside of the text box! Also, this.value works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are actually a number of wonderful tools out there such as the [Closure JavaScript compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/), which can perform type-checking and other static analysis of JavaScript, the [Chrome developer tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html), which make it possible to test JavaScript on the fly and observe and debug the execution of JavaScript, and Firefox's [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) add-on which is comparable to the developer tools built into Chrome. (See also [my post about type-safety and testability of JavaScript](https://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/software-engineering/javascript-a-delightfully-testable-and-typesafe-language) in which I express my surprise at the great tooling).

I did a test to see if 'onchange' was the problem in Chrome by visiting 'about:blank', and inserting*:

```
<input type="text" onchange="document.write('changed')" />
```

And I observed that the change event is not called until you hit enter and finalize the content of the box. Is the bug that you were expecting it to trigger each time a new letter was entered? You might want to load your page in Chrome or Firebug and look at the script console to see if there are any errors.

*In the developer tools in Chrome, it is very easy to alter the DOM of a page to try out new things, and add arbitrary JavaScript in the console to prototype things before implementing them.

Also, you may find the [Google JavaScript style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml) useful to avoid staying out of hot water.

Answer (score 0):

On change does not fire until you move focus out of the input box.

If you want a good debugger use one of:

- Chrome/Safari's webkit inspector (aka developer tools)
- The Firebug addon in Firefox
- The developer tools in IE8/9

These tools are every bit as good at debugging Javascript as IDEs for C#/C++.

Answer (score 0):

To debug javascript, I would recommend using the javascript console in Chrome's web inspector or the Firebug extension for firefox. Opera also has their own javascript console called dragonfly.

Taken from a Google Chome help page:

There are a couple of ways to view JavaScript errors and work to debug them in Google Chrome:

JavaScript Console: click the Page menu icon and select Developer > JavaScript Console. From here, you'll be able to view errors in the JavaScript execution, and enter additional JavaScript commands to execute.

JavaScript Debugger: available as Page menu icon > Developer > Debug JavaScript, the debugger provides a command prompt from which you can set breakpoints, backtrace, and more. Type help at the debugger command line to get started.