# ASP.NET AJAX to Code behind function call Error

Tags: asp.net, ajax, error-handling, code-behind

I am using the following call to send data back to the server:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "MyTestPage.aspx/UpdateData",
  data: updates,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (msg) {
                 alert('Success!');
  },
  error: function (msg) {
                  alert('Failure!');
  }
});
```

The code behind looks like

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace TestNamespace
{
    public partial class MyTestPage: System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public static bool UpdateData(string IDs, string Values)
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

From Chrome the request pay load i.e. value of the UI updates variable is: `{ IDS : "21TOK31" , VALUES : "2TOK2"}`

The request does not hit the code behind function and the ajax function always goes to the failure block because of the error.

The request hits the code behind function when no data is being passed and the code behind function has no parameters.

I am new to using JSON in ASP.NET. Can someone please guide me to what the problem might be? And how best it might be solved.

Comment: One of the error I found out was in the code behind function definition

 public static bool UpdateData(string IDs, string Values)

The name of the code behind parameters should be the same as the JSON objects, in the case above this should have been:

 public static bool UpdateData(string IDS, string VALUES)

It's case sensitive, so one has to take care of that too. Me being new and a school boy error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify the error function to be like this:

```
error: function (xhr, err) { alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status + "\nresponseText: " + xhr.responseText); }
```

and you will see the exact error.

personally i just put breakpoints inside the function giving me problems and run it locally to debug,

Comment: if i were you i'd just send two form fields with ids, then values. instead of using json. change the data to data: { id: "id string", values: "values" }. change the data type to html. then in your .net function, refer to the values passed as my.request.form("id") and my.request.form("values") instead of using parameters for the function.

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot:

1. Open the [Chrome debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420/how-do-you-launch-the-javascript-debugger-in-google-chrome)
2. Click on the "Network" tab
3. Submit the ajax request as you've been doing
4. You should see the request to MyTestPage.aspx/UpdateData - click on it
5. Under the "Preview" tab, you'll see the error message that .NET is returning

If you're still having problems, post the result of that, which will give you the real error that's happening.

Comment: That's where I got the following in my actual request:

From Chrome the request pay load i.e. value of the UI updates variable is: { IDS : "21TOK31" , VALUES : "2TOK2"}

Comment: Right - I figured that's how you proved what was being sent on the request.  I was providing an alternative way to seeing the response from the server without modifying the code.  The "Preview" tab shows the .NET server error page in the format you're used to as a .NET developer.  Sometimes that's easier to look at than alert windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following, does it work:

```
var updates = '{"IDs":"21TOK31","Values":"2TOK2"}';
```

There are also configuration settings in the webconfig file that need set, but I make the assumption you have those due to your empty return value working.

One other thing you might need is a converter due to the format that asp returns data:(in your javascript ajax call)

```
converters: {
    "json jsond": function(msg)
    {
        return msg.hasOwnProperty('d') ? msg.d : msg;
    }
},
```

and change:

```
contentType: "application/json",
```