# jQuery calendar does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, uidatepicker

At http://tinyurl.com/3rcedo2 I have a WordPress 3.3.1 Cforms 11.6.1 form that is supposed to load a calendar pop-up that is working together with jQuery 1.7.1 The calendar no longer pops up when clicked. The trigger seems to no longer work. Any ideas why?

Comment: You should isolate problem. Open javascript console and look for related warnings and errors. Then post here this information.

Comment: This is the error. Error: Image corrupt or truncated: <unknown>
Source File: <unknown>
Line: 0

Comment: is your problem about datepicker

Comment: How can I open javascript console from Chrome? Or is this only possible from Firefox? What is the issue with datepicker Josh?

Comment: Checked for errors in FF and found only Chrome and other browser related errors so far. Trying to find error mentioned.

Comment: Also found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420/how-do-you-launch-the-javascript-debugger-in-google-chrome for Chrome Jscript debugging , but Chrome detects no errors ..

Comment: I have upgraded to V 13.0 . Calendar pop-up is working, but styling in Firefox is off plus I am receiving an error that calendar.css cannot be founded as it is being looked for in the root of the site while it should be looked for in plugins/cforms/styling

Comment: Well, all seem to be well with the styling now. Had to kill WP Supercache as it seems to mess up the homepage slider but that is another issues. Datepicker does run despite the calendar.css 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally forgot to answer this question. After debugging using Firebug and the JavaScript console I found the culprit. It was a JScript conflict issue