# Is there a JavaScript function to make Google Chrome break into the debugger?

Tags: javascript

I am looking for something like `Debugger.Launch()` in .NET, which breaks into the debugger programmatically.

I am not looking for a cross browser way to do it, just Google Chrome is good enough.

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420/how-do-you-launch-the-javascript-debugger-in-google-chrome

Comment: It is similar, but I am looking for a programmatic way, so that the browser stops there automatically without any actions from me. The answer to that question talks about an interactive way, although there is a response which answers my question exactly.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, you need to use:

```
debugger;
```

The script will break exactly at line where you put `debugger` keyword.

To view it, you will first need to open **Tools -> Developer tools** (or pressing **F12**) and then by selecting your file from **Scripts** tab.