# what function is being called?

Tags: user-defined-functions

i am not sure that this is the right place to ask this question, but i will anyway. i have only been working with html / javascript & jquery for about 2 months, but i have learned a little.
this is what i am trying to do. i have a free image gallery that i managed to included in a website i am trying to make. the gallery works fine, and i have set it up so that on top of each image is a button that fires a short .mp4.
it works fine, but when i click the gallery button to show the next page of pictures (about 15 per page), there are my old buttons. i think, just maybe if i could figure out what js or jq function id being called i may be able to swap in new buttons. 
but i cannot understand what is happening. i looked for an onclick, but what they use is a bunch of "this" statements. i am pretty sure they are using an anchor tag to flip the page, but i can't figure out what is being called.
so i came across this site, and after about 10 attempts, finally got the thing to let me join. 
i'm hoping i can post the code and maybe somebody could tell me what is happening.
i guess this wasn't much of a question, just an appeal for assistance.

Comment: You question is a bit unclear. Yes, you can post all the code you want! People will  be able to help you better that way.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how you can debug your code? If you are using Chrome, you can use its [Javascript debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66434/303598). Similarly, [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is a good developer plugin for Firefox.