# How debug javascript and PHP script in the same file together with Eclipse

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, eclipse

Can I debug javascript and PHP in the same file with eclipse?

I've tried a lot but it does not work. I have "Eclipse for PHP Developers"

```
Version: Helios Release
Build id: 20100617-1415"
```

I've installed JRE/JDK. I've installed zendserver/wamp. I've installed jsdt,
but I could not run JavaScript on Eclipse.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean to click Yes or No to the answers ?

Comment: Not really -- he means to click the Check on the answer you chose, or the answer that helps the most even if not perfect. That gives both you and the person who helped you credit for doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You debug JavaScript in the browser.

[IE8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)+, [Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420/how-do-you-launch-the-javascript-debugger-in-google-chrome), and [Safari](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/DebuggingYourWebsite/DebuggingYourWebsite.html) have JavaScript debuggers built in.

Firefox has [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com).

Comment: Yes.but I have example that I can't debug http://www.centerwow.com/guide1/TitleLinkCoolie.html

Comment: this link should need to pass parameter via cookie from one file to secend file and I have a problem to slove it. the debug of browser skip of some line code.

Comment: @bamba1 You cannot debug js and php with the same debugger at once and it would quite pointless to do so anyway. They are different languages in totally different contexts and usually running on different machines with relatively little communication going on in between them.