# Create DIV in for loop?(JS)

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

Is it possible to create a div with a unique ID using a for loop?

```
for (var i = 0, n = 4; i < n; i++) {
var divTag = document.createElement("div");
divTag.id = "div"i;
divTag.innerHTML = Date();
document.body.appendChild(divTag);
}
```

Shouldn't this code produce 4 Unique DIVs containing the current date? At the moment it returns nothing.

Comment: on a side note, `"div"i` is a syntax error and, in javascript, syntax errors prevent any further execution of javascript, which is why nothing happens.

Comment: Learn to use a [debugger](http://stackoverflow.com/q/66420/352796).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
divTag.id = "div" + i;
```

And it will produce unique ID

Comment: Blind mistake, thank you very much guys. Nice fast answer btw, will accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
divTag.id = 'div' + i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
divTag.id = "div" + i;
```

instead of

```
divTag.id = "div"i;
```

Then it should work