# Json-encoded JavaScript with Ajax throws an error message

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I have an html doc that contains:

```
        <li id="li_273" data-pricefield="special" data-pricevalue="0" >
        <label class="description" for="element_273">Helium Foil Balloon #1 </label>
            <div>
                <input type="text" class="element text medium" id="element_273" name="element_273" size="30" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" id="element_273_price" name="element_273_price" value="">

            </div> 
       </li>
```

So then, that area is an ajax drop down menu. From that ajax/php drop down I am able to execute an onclick command - this is what I have:

```
'onclick' => 'document.getElementById(\'li_273\').data(\'pricevalue\',\'1.00\');',
```

It all gets json_encoded and this is the portion that it returns:

```
"onclick":"document.getElementById('li_273').data('pricevalue','1.00');",
```

But yet I get an error message when I select something from the ajax menu and onclick:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLLIElement> has no method 'data'
```

I cannot for the life of me figure this out and all I need it to do is just update a price that is on the page.

UPDATE: here's the rest of the code to try to get it to actually calculate
the JavaScript on the page:

```
        $('#main_body li[data-pricefield="special"]').delegate('onclick','change', function(e) {
        var temp = $(this).attr("id").split('_');
        var element_id = temp[1];

        var pricedef = $(this).data('pricedef');
        if(pricedef == null){
            pricedef = 0;
        }

        $("#li_" + element_id).data("pricevalue",pricedef);
        calculate_total_payment();
           });
```

What seems to be missing? Because it doesn't update the total on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.data` is a jquery function and you are probably trying to call it on a dom object. Make sure you have jQuery loaded on your page and then do:

```
jQuery('#li_273').data('pricevalue','1.00');
```

Comment: that's seemed to have taken care of the error. How can I check it for sure? If I try viewing source it obviously sets the price back to 0. Is there a way I can see it to make sure it's updated? I am using Chrome's Developer tools

Comment: If your using chrome or firefox load the page, perform your actions that will set the data and then go into the javascript console and type `jQuery('#li_273').data('pricevalue');`. If the console returns `1.00` then you know its working.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420/how-do-you-launch-the-javascript-debugger-in-google-chrome for how to debug javascript in chrome

Comment: again - perfect - that's what it returns. Now I think my other stuff is off a bit. Stand by for more code.

Comment: If you have a different problem you should post another question on stackoverflow and you will get more answers. As for this one you should consider it answered.