# How to calculate the length of an encoded string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arabic

so i have an arabic string then i encode it using encodeURIComponent,
 then i try to know the length from the encoded string but this code don't work why? http://jsfiddle.net/mCwaj/

```
var str="قال على";
var encd=encodeURIComponent(str);
alert(encd);
alert(custom_length(encd));
function custom_length(str){
var tab=str.match(/%../g);
return tab.length;
}
```

the result should be 7 but function returns 13, what i know is that an arabic encoded alphabet is composed like %(letter|number)(letter|number)

Comment: Open your browser's developer console. This is the first step in debugging.

Comment: what console, i don't know how to open the console ?

Comment: [`Ctlr` + `Shift` + `I`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420/how-do-you-launch-the-javascript-debugger-in-google-chrome), see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/988363/1048572

Comment: Almost all browsers have built-in developer tools. They are an indispensable tool for debugging code. I think some browsers will open them with `f12`, but look through your menus or preferences to find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the non-encoded `str` to your function instead of `encd`. Therefore, the regex does not [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and the result `null` throws an exception on accessing its `length` property.

Comment: thanks bergi but that was a typo in the code, the real problem is that the real string length is 7 and the result is 13

Comment: Um, no? `%D9%82%D8%A7%D9%84%20%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%89` has 13 escape sequences, and that's what your `custom_length` counts. If you want 7, you should try `decodeURIComponent(str).length`

Comment: If you want the string length of 7, why not (str.length)? That gives 7

Answer (score 0):

try using "escape()" instead of "encodeURIComponent()"

```
//14 charachters
var str="مرحبا أنا ياسر";  

var result=custom_length(escape(str));

alert(result); //it'll display 14

function custom_length(str){
   var tab=str.match(/%../g);
   return tab.length;
}
```

Demo:`http://jsfiddle.net/ysinjab/KDyhp/`