# Object Stopping All Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

Learning Javascript and have an issue I can't seem to resolve.  I created an object and a couple instances, and did some document.write on them.  The problem is, they won't work.  The further problem is, it stops *all* the Javascript from working.  When I put in a window.alert at the very beginning to ensure I had it linked to my HTML right, that wouldn't work either (but the window.alert DOES WORK when the object is commented out). 
Anyone care to explain what I'm doing wrong here?

```
window.alert("TEST!!!");

function car(seats, engine, theradio) {
this.seats = seats;
this.engine = engine;
this.theradio = theradio;
}

var work_car = new car("cloth", "V-6", "tape deck");
var fun_car = new car("leather", "V-8", "CD Player");
var engine_type = work_car.engine;
var seat_type = fun_car.seats;
var radio_type = fun_car.theradio;

document.write("I want a car with " + seat_type + " seats." <br />);
document.write("Oh, and it should have " + engine_type + " and a " + radio_type ".");
```

Comment: You have syntax errors in the  `document.write` commands... Don't know if that is just an error when pasting the code here...

Comment: Never use `document.write`. Use methods for DOM manipulating, like `appendChild` instead.

Comment: @vis - in this case I think it is just used for debugging and `console.log` would be even better.

Comment: One of the most important things is to learn [how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Comment: @fel - that is an **awesome** link to add to my `[so]` bookmark folder :P

Answer (score 4):

The `<br />` inside the first `document.write` is outside of quotes. That throwing errors.

The other issue is that there is no `+` sign after `radio.type`.

You should however, be using `console.log` instead of `document.write`.

If you really need to append it to the html page, you should use `appendChild`

Comment: If this really is the root of the problem then this post should really be closed as too localized...

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
document.write("I want a car with " + seat_type + " seats.<br />");
document.write("Oh, and it should have " + engine_type + " and a " + radio_type + ".");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax errors in your code. The easiest way to view errors like that is using a debugging console, which most browsers have built in.  For example, here's how you launch the chrome debugger:

[How do you launch the JavaScript debugger in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420/how-do-you-launch-the-javascript-debugger-in-google-chrome)