# Chrome Developer tools: How to disable code auto complete?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am experimenting with Chrome DevTool's beautiful Workspaces / in-devtools code editor in the source panel, set up roughly like the accepted answer here: [Chrome developer tools: View Console and Sources views in separate views/vertically tiled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537738/chrome-developer-tools-view-console-and-sources-views-in-separate-views-vertica)

So far, it's awesome. The one drawback is that I detest code completion dropdowns and the browser entering things for me. When it gives me two quotes and I've only typed one, I really get irritated.

Anyway, is there a way to stop it automatically <del>breaking my code</del> trying to help out? If I really must, I'll revert back to my old gedit workflow, but then I'd be a sad bear.

Comment: It auto suggests for me too aggressively! I end up with mangled words that contain parts of what I was typing and what it wants to auto suggest. Anyone else getting this issue?

Comment: @DanielSokolowski: You may be aware that it's been fixed now since your comment was a year ago. If not, consider this a heads up :)

Comment: Is annoying, I ended up using Firefox as they have a simple setting to disable autocomplete on the console page

Comment: related: [How can I make Enter run code instead of accepting an autocomplete suggestion in Chrome Devtools?](/q/53973995/11107541)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks (perhaps) to [the bug that was filed (#308863)](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=308863), this is now a feature in Google Chrome.

To disable autocomplete in Chrome Dev Tools:

1. Open **Dev Tools** if it's not open already.
2. Open **Settings**. For me, this is a cog icon in the top right corner of the devtools window.
3. The **General** section of settings should hopefully be open automatically. If not, select it and scroll down to **Sources**
4. Untick/uncheck Autocompletion. Yay!

Comment: Note this *doesn't* seem to disable the autocomplete in the console, only in the "sources" tab. Took me a while to figure that out  As far as I can tell, there is no way to disable it in the console :-/

Comment: in Chrome 112.0.5615.49 now, for me, this *does* affect the behavior in the console

Comment: yeah, for some reason my chrome changed and defaulted to the opposite. I had to look up this answer to *enable* it in the console

Answer (score 6):

No, as of Chrome 32.0.1673.0 there is no way to disable quote/brace auto-insertion and/or code completion.

Feel free to file a bug at crbug.com for DevTools, and we will fix it up.

Comment: Thanks, filed here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&q=autocomplete%20devtools&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&id=308863&thanks=308863&ts=1382087148

Comment: I don't mind auto-complete, but is it supposed to noticably lag?  I type pretty fast and recently I have started noticing that after I type something in (e.g.) the console and hit enter, I have to wait several seconds as it tries to autocomplete on every character I have already typed!

Comment: looks like it was fixed for a while then removed again.  :( .  Open to disable autocomplete is missing in version Version 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit).   It's probably been gone for some time.

Comment: Bleh. Chrome's not really that smart with this stuff. Go write `foo)` in a snippet, and press delete. You'll be left with `fo` – it removes both the parens and its preceding character.