# How to disable autocomplete in the Javascript console for Chrome 70?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am currently learning javascript and have encountered an annoyance. When using the Chrome javascript console it will pop up an autocomplete window for whatever I am typing. I read that disabling autocomplete from history and eager evaluation would fix this but I am still getting popups and suggestions. Is there any way to get rid of this?

[image: autocomplete window]

Comment: can you share a screenshot?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19427835/chrome-developer-tools-how-to-disable-code-auto-complete but the solution there only works for *"Sources"* panel, not for the Console...

Answer (score -1):

To turn off autocompletion in Chrome's console, click the gear icon  and clear the Autocomplete box.

[image: screenshot showing location of gear and checkbox for autocomplete]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23625201)

Comment: Whatever man. It aint a link-only answer. I explained in text for a reason.

Comment: This does not solve the problem, unfortunately. It only prevents autocomplete from showing previously typed commands, not source methods like the OP shows in the screenshot.