# How to open the "Console" tab in Google DevTools alongside any other tab so I can see the contents of them both at the same time?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Sometimes I need to see the contents of the `Console` tab of the Google DevTools alongside the contents of another tab so that I don't have to go back and forth between them. How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome developer tools: View Console and Sources views in separate views/vertically tiled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537738/chrome-developer-tools-view-console-and-sources-views-in-separate-views-vertica)

Comment: Seriously? All such basic info is available on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press the `Esc` key on your keyboard to toggle between showing or hiding the `Console` tab in the Google DevTools alongside any other open tab.

Google DevTools can be opened by pressing `F12` or `Ctrl+Shift+C`.