# How to know the possible HTML attributes of an element (EG <img>) in JS?

Tags: javascript, userscripts, html

How to know the possible HTML attributes of an element (EG ) in JS?

How can I get to know a list of possible HTML attributes for a particular HTML node?

For example, when writing a userscript, I would like to know the possible HTML attributes of such nodes:

```
var images = d.getElementsByTagName('img');
```

something like: `images[i].src`

Comment: there is a way to do so. Look my updated answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers do not expose that information. You would need to get or create a machine readable specification for the markup language you are using.

HTML 4, for example, has [DTDs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3) that you could parse:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd
- http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd
- http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the properties of an object with `for in` like this:

```
var keys = [];
for (var key in obj) { 
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) {
    keys.push(key);
  }
}
```

Or use `Object.keys(obj)` which will return an array of keys, but this will not work in older browsers – see [compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/).

**UPD**. Misunderstood the question, for all possible values for DOM element you need to look at HTML DTDs as in Quentin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16832112/236135). It would still be possible to set arbitrary attributes though.

Comment: possible attributes and set properties are not the same thing.

Comment: clearly communicated question and vaguely communicated question are also not the same thing

Answer (score -2):

> Try this [Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zjyGJ/)

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var allAttributes =Object.keys(image[0]);
```

Comment: How to see a console window there? I also tried with Firebug but with no success. (Sorry but I haven't used it before).

Comment: press f12 in chrome and then see the right most label in the header. just click there.and u r in console. !!

Comment: or alternatively : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420/how-do-you-launch-the-javascript-debugger-in-google-chrome