# `binding.pry` for javascript console?

Tags: javascript, ruby, read-eval-print-loop, pry

In Ruby, I can type `binding.pry` anywhere in my code and at that point of execution my console will enter a REPL where I have access to all local variables, can make changes, and execute any arbitrary code.

Example:

```
# foo.rb
require 'pry'
n = 5
binding.pry
puts "your number is #{n}"
```

When I run it:

```
$ ruby foo.rb

From: /Users/cgenco/Desktop/foo.rb @ line 4 :

    1: # foo.rb
    2: require 'pry'
    3: n = 5
 => 4: binding.pry
    5: puts "your  number is #{n}"

[1] pry(main)> n = 100
=> 100
[2] pry(main)> exit
your number is 100
```

This is an incredible tool in debugging, especially for situations that require a complicated setup: I can just type `binding.pry` at the spot I need more code, mess around, figure out what code needs to written, then add the polished code to the actual source code.

Is there a tool like [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) for javascript that works in a browser console?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most browsers have developer tools that are quite similar to this.

In Chrome, for example, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to bring up the developer tools panel. Click on the "Sources" tab and you can browse any JavaScript files that have been loaded. From here you can set *breakpoints* by clicking in the left margin. Now when you reload the page, JavaScript execution will pause at the line you indicated.

At the bottom of the panel there is a "Show console" button that will open up a REPL you can play around with.

Here is a screenshot illustrating everything I just mentioned:

[image: Screenshot of Chrome developer tools on StackOverflow]

There are similar tools in Firefox, IE, Safari, and Opera. Just Google for "developer tools [your browser of choice]" to learn more about them.

Comment: awesome, thanks a lot, this is the first time I managed to follow through instructions on how to set pry-like console in js, others were just confusing.

Answer (score 31):

Try with `debugger;` in your code as [this answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66431/1004046). Your *browser developer tools* must be open.

Comment: Ahh perfect! This is precisely what I was looking for - can't believe I didn't already know about it.

Comment: Note to future self: add `debugger` at some point in your node script, then run it with `node inspect SCRIPT.js`, then type "cont" and hit enter, then when your script hits the `debugger` line it'll stop. To enter a REPL type "repl" and hit enter.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to mention that Node.js has a nice thing called Debugger.

Super short tutorial:

1. is to run your app like this:

`node debug appname.js`

2. instead of the usual

`node appname.js`

Do yourself a favor see: https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html I posted this because I found lots of ways to do this that require dependancies before I found the debugger tool!

Answer (score 1):

~9 years after asking this question I stumbled on exactly what I was looking for: [pryjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pryjs).

Include it with either `import pry from "pryjs"` or `const pry = require("pryjs")` then invoke it with `eval(pry.it)` instead of `binding.pry`.

It works how you'd expect.

2023 edit: it looks like `pryjs` hasn't been updated in several years and isn't working.