# How to get the constructor's parent inside the constructor function (JS)

Tags: javascript

I have a bit complicated JS Objects structure:

```
var Players = {};

Players.Player = function (color) {
  this.color = color; //the color can be either black or white
  Players[color] = this;
}
Players.Player.prototpe.Piece = function () {
  return this.parent.color //of course, this is not valid
}
new Players.Player("black");
new Players.Player("white");
new Players["black"].Piece(); //here I want to get "black"
new Players["white"].Piece(); //here I want to get "white"
```

I hope I described my problem well enough. I want to be able to return the color of the paret of the constructor, meaning to replace `this.parent.color` with a better command that will return "black" on the first piece and "white" on the second piece.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly there is a typo in your code

`Players.Player.prototpe.Piece` should be  `Players.Player.prototype.Piece`

if you are using a browser like chrome , you can easily see and fix these errors by firing up the developer console. see [How to debug in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420/how-do-you-launch-the-javascript-debugger-in-google-chrome)

now moving on to the actual problem on returning the colors, you have to modify the code

from `return this.parent.color` to `return this.color`.this should fix the problem.

**this** is a keyword in javascript that can correctly identify the object instances, depending upon the context on which the function(here piece) is executing.

```
Players.Player.prototype.Piece = function () {
  return this.color //this is now valid
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/zixitebijeko/1/edit)