# How to pause JS script execution at a specific line?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I have a script which I want to allow users to debug right in the browser. I can get line numbers for the breakpoints and I can get local variable values what I'm curious about is how do I pause the actual script execution at a specific line? I tried putting hidden sleep() calls along with the local vars dumping code, wonder if there's more elegant solution for the problem?

Just a clarification - the console isn't available to me. I can only use regular JS script features. I use chrome dev tools for years but never experienced the need for emulating `debugger;` instruction by JS code before.

Comment: see  here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420/how-do-you-launch-the-javascript-debugger-in-google-chrome

This is the command:
debugger;

Comment: or use `console.log`s everywhere :)

Comment: if it's for educating purpose, maybe the best way is to inform your user to open the console instead of finding a may-not-exist tricky way.

Comment: not it's not. I thought of visualizing the interim execution state along with giving access to the actual var values. The first aspect is even more useful.

Answer (score 2):

Use the developer console of your web browser. For example in Firefox, hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, find the specific line, and click on it. It will stop the execution, when it reaches that line.

You can use the usual debugging steps too:

- Step Over <kbd>F10</kbd>,
- Step Into <kbd>F11</kbd>
- Step Return <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>

PS: I also recommend using the [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) extension, I find it invaluable in my job. It is a developer toolbar with many neat features, and better performance (at least it seems that way for me).

Answer (score 0):

There is no inline way to `pause` javascript however using the chrome debugger tools you can have it stop at a certain breakpoint.

In chrome:
**Ctrl+Shift+I** > **sources** > **script.js** > **click a line number** > **refresh page**

Answer (score 0):

Use google chrome console <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> go to **Source tab** search the js file and click on line number for put a breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

Use the `debugger;` statement:

> The debugger statement invokes any available debugging functionality, such as setting a breakpoint. If no debugging functionality is available, this statement has no effect.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger

Comment: How do I get it working just in the browser without using a console? I'd thought it'll simply get ignored it console isn't active

Comment: It will, and you don't. Why would your users want to let you hijack their browser?

Comment: cos I love my users and try doing anything to make their lives easier:)

Comment: Well dev tools cannot be opened programmatically. With javascript being asynchronous, consider attaching your script to a callback of the *big red button* type. But then this becomes a usability question, not a programming one