# How to activate the JavaScript debugger in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript, i want to know how to activate debugging in google Chrome. Please someone help me out. I am using Mac book.

Comment: There is no need to activate, just open the console and put a breakpoint under the appropriate source.

Comment: How to open the console?

Comment: right click on the page and "Inspect element" , touch your mouse pad with 2 fingers will works as right click on mac

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/shortcuts#opening-devtools then go to "sources" tab.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you launch the javascript debugger in Google Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420/how-do-you-launch-the-javascript-debugger-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reading this web page:

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Hopefully it will answer your questions.