# AngularJS Scope.Feed Looping

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

How do i Loop this data using AngularJS?

In Laravel, I can do a var_dump in HTML but i'm not familiar with Angular. Any advice on degbugging and how do i Loop this?

$scope.feed = result.data;
[image]

```
.controller('FeedEntriesCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $http, FeedList, $q, $ionicLoading, BookMarkService) {
        $scope.feed = [];

        $scope.doRefresh = function() {
            $http.get("http://www.com/api/admin/v1/getListing?token=www")
                .then(function (result) {
                    $scope.feed = result;
                    console.log(result);
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
                }, function (reason) {
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
                });
        };

        $scope.doRefresh();

        $scope.bookmarkPost = function(post){
            $ionicLoading.show({ template: 'Post Saved!', noBackdrop: true, duration: 1000 });
            BookMarkService.bookmarkFeedPost(post);
        };
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller there are two `get` request for getting list.

```
 $http.get('http://www.com/api/admin/v1/getListing?token=www')
```

and

```
FeedList.get('http://www.com/api/admin/v1/getListing?token=wwww')
```

Here second request send on success respones of first request. It is not require. Remove one request from code.

Other thing is:

```
$scope.feed = result;
```

Here `result` is assigningto `$scope.feed` variable so you can access only `feed` object in `DOM` not `data` variable. You are trying to access `data` object in `ng-repeat`

`data` is object of `feed` so you can access is using `.`(dot) property.

```
feed.data
```

From image it is not visible about `id` but if id is available object from array then rest of code will work fine. You have to just change `data` to `feed.data` in `ng-repeat`

```
 <div class="list category-feeds">
      <a ng-repeat="source in feed.data" class="item item-icon-right" ui-sref="app.feed-entries({categoryId: source.id, sourceId: (source.id | slugify)})">
        <div class="thumbnail-outer">
          <pre-img ratio="_1_1" helper-class="">
            <img class="thumbnail" ng-src="{{source.id}}" spinner-on-load>
          </pre-img>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span class="title">{{source.id}}</span>
          <p class="description">{{source.id}}</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div
```

Comment: I Mean, the image is what i added to scope.. and i have got a feeling somewhere else is wrong. How do you debug to see if the data was even being pushed to HTML page

Comment: Take a look at [debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging) and [debugger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420/how-do-you-launch-the-javascript-debugger-in-google-chrome)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92335/discussion-between-flyingatom-and-sarjan-desai).