# Uncaught TypeError of undefined (length and value properties)

Tags: javascript

I continued with my Hangman game, and i finished the code.

But i got new 2 errors :

> ahorcado.js:146 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>   ahorcado.js:118 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

```
var palabra = "Perro"
var hombre,l, espacio;

var Ahorcado = function (con) {
    this.contexto = con;
    this.maximo = 5;
    this.intentos = 0;
    this.vivo = true;

    this.dibujar();
}

Ahorcado.prototype.dibujar = function () {

    var dibujo = this.contexto;

    dibujo.beginPath();
    dibujo.moveTo(150,100);
    dibujo.lineTo(150,50);
    dibujo.lineTo(400,50);
    dibujo.lineTo(400,350);
    dibujo.lineWidth = 15;
    dibujo.strokeStyle = '#000'
    dibujo.stroke();
    dibujo.closePath();

    if (this.intentos > 0) {
        dibujo.beginPath();
        dibujo.arc(150, 140, 40, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        dibujo.strokeStyle = '#f00'
        dibujo.lineWidth = 5;
        dibujo.stroke();
        dibujo.closePath();

        if (this.intentos > 1) {
            dibujo.beginPath();
            dibujo.moveTo(150,180);
            dibujo.lineTo(150,250);
            dibujo.strokeStyle = '#f00'
            dibujo.lineWidth = 5;
            dibujo.stroke();
            dibujo.closePath();

            if (this.intentos > 2) {
                dibujo.beginPath();
                dibujo.moveTo(120,220);
                dibujo.lineTo(150,180);
                dibujo.lineTo(180,220);
                dibujo.strokeStyle = '#f00'
                dibujo.lineWidth = 5;
                dibujo.stroke();
                dibujo.closePath();

                if (this.intentos > 3) {
                    dibujo.beginPath();
                    dibujo.moveTo(120,290);
                    dibujo.lineTo(150,250);
                    dibujo.lineTo(180,290);
                    dibujo.strokeStyle = '#f00'
                    dibujo.lineWidth = 5;
                    dibujo.stroke();
                    dibujo.closePath();

                    if (this.intentos > 4) {

                        dibujo.beginPath();
                        dibujo.moveTo(125,120);
                        dibujo.lineTo(145,145);
                        dibujo.moveTo(145,120);
                        dibujo.lineTo(125,145);

                        dibujo.moveTo(155,120);
                        dibujo.lineTo(175,145);
                        dibujo.moveTo(175,120);
                        dibujo.lineTo(155,145);

                        dibujo.strokeStyle = 'blue';
                        dibujo.linewidth = 5;
                        dibujo.stroke();
                        dibujo.closePath();
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Ahorcado.prototype.trazar = function () {
    this.intentos++;
    if (this.intentos >= this.maximo) {
        this.vivo = false;
        alert('Estas muerto')
    }
    this.dibujar();
}



function iniciar() {
    var l = document.getElementById('letra');
    var b = document.getElementById('boton');
    var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
    canvas.width = 500;
    canvas.height = 400;
    var contexto = canvas.getContext('2d');
    hombre = new Ahorcado(contexto); 

    espacio = new Array(palabra.length);

    b.addEventListener('click', agregarLetra)


    mostrarPista(espacio);

}

function agregarLetra() {
    var letra = l.value
    var p;
    mostrarPalabra(palabra, hombre, letra);
    for(p in palabra){
        if (letra == palabra[p]) {
            espacio[p] = letra;
            encontrado = true;
        }
    }

    mostrarPista(espacio);

    if (!encontrado) {
        ahorcado.trazar
    }
}

function mostrarPalabra(palabra, ahorcado, letra) {
    var encontrado = false;
    letra = letra.toUppercase();


}

function mostrarPista(palabra, espacio) {
    var pista = document.getElementById('pista');
    var texto = '';
    var i = 0;
    var largo = espacio.length;

    for (i = 0; i < largo; i++) {
        if (espacio[i] != undefined) {
            texto = texto + espacio[i] + '';
        }
        else{
            texto += '_ '
        }
    }

    pista.innerText = texto;
}
```

Comment: The errors are pretty clear.  You're trying to read properties from variables which aren't initialized and don't have objects to read.  When you debug this, where does it happen?  What objects are `undefined`?  Where do you *expect* them to be defined?  Stack Overflow is not a replacement for a debugger.

Comment: in addition to @David this may be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420/how-do-you-launch-the-javascript-debugger-in-google-chrome if you place a `debugger` statement on line 117 and try to find what is `undefined` and see: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging AND https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger

Comment: Thanks for all replies, im in learning process, by now, i dont now how to debug, thanks for all suggetions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 118, `var letra = l.value` - `l` is `undefined` 
Line 146: `var largo = espacio.length;` - `espacio` is `undefined`.

Try to figure out where this variables comes from and why they are `undefined`, we can't solve you issues if the code is in another language tho.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the variable `espacio` *is* undefined, just as the error message says, as you never call `iniciar`, which would initialize it.

Comment: I called `iniciar();` in HTML file. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler 'agregarLetra' does not know 'l' (btw bad variable name, because it does not explain what that variable is for).
So instead of:

```
var letra = l.value
```

Try:

```
l = document.getElementById('letra').value;
```

Alternatively in your 'iniciar' function write:

```
l = document.getElementById('letra');
```

Instead of:

```
var l = document.getElementById('letra');
```

The 'var l' saves the node only to a new local variable.
That should solve l. 118.

The error from l. 146 is caused by the fact that you forgot to pass the 'palabra' parameter when calling 'mostrarPista'. Your function is defined with 2 parameters:

```
function mostrarPista(palabra, espacio) {
```

but called with only one parameter (l. 128):

```
mostrarPista(espacio);
```