# Why error message is not displaying

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function validate() { 
            var a = document.form.name.value;

            if(!(a)) { 
                document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "*Please fill required"; 
            } else { 
                document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = ""; 
            }
        } 
        </script> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <form method= "post" name="form" onsubmit="return validate();"> 
            Name :<input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
            <div id="errorBox"> </div> <br> 
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /> 
            <input type="Reset" name="Reset" /> 
    </body>
```

Don't know why that error message is not showing?

Comment: Please try to put breakpoints and see what the value of a and what happens exactly

Comment: hoe to put breakpoints chenop??

Comment: That's a good basic question - check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420/how-do-you-launch-the-javascript-debugger-in-google-chrome

Comment: please, add the relevant html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your following code

```
var a = document.form.name.value;
if( a == "" )
        {
    document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "*Please fill required";

  }
```

with this code

```
var a = document.getElementById("name").value;
if(!(a))
{
    document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "*Please fill required";

}
```

If still issue not solved, kindly show us ur html code so that we check is there any error or not.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
function validate()
{
 var a = document.form.name.value;
  
  if(!(a))
   {
      document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "*Please fill required";
      
    }
 
else
{
document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "";
      
}

}   



</script>
</head>
    
<body>
<form method= "post"   name="form"   onsubmit="return validate();">
     Name :<input type="text" id="name" name="name" /><div id="errorBox"> </div>
  <br> 
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /> 
   <input type="Reset"  name="Reset"

Comment: Nothing happens Imran ...Dono how to post my complete code thatswhy posted in comment area

Comment: u welcome, if it works for u. always remember to accept answer for future users, by clicking on tick symbol.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, an empty string is not the same as a `null` value or an `undefined`... but they all resolve to false in a condition !

Try this:

```
 if(!a){
     // your code
 }
```

Have a look at this fiddle for a working solution: https://jsfiddle.net/wvofbjdk/

If it does not work in your code, then the error is elsewhere. Have a look at the console for errors (see this link to get started on chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/?hl=en).

Comment: Whether in IF or else if  derlin