# Javascript alert if text is found on another page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently using this code to show a popup if the text is found on that page. However, I wanted to show that popup on other pages if the text exists on the original page.

Example
Text is on /invoice
I navigate to /payment
Pop up still runs

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function(){
    //If the body element of the page contains 'one hour turnaround' then trigger an alert
    if(document.body.innerHTML.toString().indexOf('one hour turnaround') > -1){
         alert("You have a ONE HOUR TURNAROUND order");
    }};
</script>
```

Comment: if you navigate to a new page, the previous page is not accessible any more.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For easy workaround, you can do this by saving the flag for this in the local storage and accessing on every page to check if that localstorage has value then show the popup otherwise not. after that 1hour time span should clear the localstorage. so now you dunction on the page wher you have that element is now

```
 window.onload = function(){
        //If the body element of the page contains 'one hour turnaround' then trigger an alert
        if(document.body.innerHTML.toString().indexOf('one hour turnaround') > -1){
              localStorage.setItem('oneHourTurnaround', "true");
               alert("You have a ONE HOUR TURNAROUND order")
               setTimeout(function(){ alert("You have a ONE HOUR TURNAROUND order"); }, 3000); // currenlty it's 3 sec
          }
        else{
            localStorage.setItem('oneHourTurnaround', "false");
        }
      }
```

and for all other page are

```
window.onload = function(){
    //If the body element of the page contains 'one hour turnaround' then trigger an alert
    if(localStorage.getItem('oneHourTurnaround')==true){
      alert("You have a ONE HOUR TURNAROUND order");
    }
 }
```

Comment: I don't have problem with being downvoted ? but can you explain ?

Comment: Let me clear up my question a bit. The code I posted lives on /page1 and the pop up works fine there. However if I navigate to /page2, I still want to see the pop up if alert is triggered on /page1

Comment: this part of the code >>>> else {localStorage.setItem('oneHourTurnaround', "false"); }};  does it go after the first code?

Comment: if element as you mentioned  is not found, then the alert is not poped up !!

Comment: First code works was just missing the spacing in one hour turnaround

Comment: "missing the spacing in one hour turnaround ?" what do you mean by this?

Comment: The code was running because there was no spacing in localStorage.setItem('oneHourTurnaround', "true"); has to be localStorage.setItem('one Hour Turnaround', "true");

Comment: thats interesting. it was not popping up until i added the space

Comment: is that so !! both variable name is same ?

Comment: Nevermind now it's working with the code you posted. Added the second code to another page but it is not working

Comment: @M.Heredia Updated second function. Please use this now !!

Comment: Nope. still nothing. It's definitely in local storage but the pop up is not occurring on the second page

Comment: well !! without space it's working on may localhost ? can you do exactly what I have done ?

Comment: I'm trying it on the live site and have also tried it on fiddle and w3schools. the first pop up works fine but the second one does nothing. however when I inspect it, its in local storage

Comment: is it possible you can show me, how you re implementing it !!

Comment: <?php
include("session.php");
include_once("codelibrary/inc/admin-header.php");
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/calendar/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
 <script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    //If the body element of the page contains 'one hour turnaround' then trigger an alert
    if(localStorage.getItem('oneHourTurnaround')==true){
      alert("You have a ONE HOUR TURNAROUND order");
    }
 }
</script>
<script src="/calendar/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>

Comment: this script is for page 2, and for page 1?

Comment: also show for page 1 ? and can you verify that is localstorgae is containging the value ?

Comment: this is page 1. code is implemented right after this code. too long to post <?php
include("session.php");
include_once("codelibrary/inc/admin-header.php");
?>
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="codelibrary/js/func_ajax.js"></script>
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="codelibrary/js/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="facebox/facebox.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> same code you posted

Comment: this is code on page 1  <script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
        //If the body element of the page contains 'one hour turnaround' then trigger an alert
        if(document.body.innerHTML.toString().indexOf('one hour turnaround') > -1){
              localStorage.setItem('oneHourTurnaround', "true");
              alert("You have a ONE HOUR TURNAROUND order");
          }
        else{
            localStorage.setItem('oneHourTurnaround', "false");
        }
      }
</script>

Comment: local storage is showing one hour turnaround value true and oneHourTurnaround value true

Comment: getting any error on console? also can you check is you localstorage is containging the value or not ? on both pages ?

Comment: On second pageor first page ?

Comment: I cleared my local storage. page 1 is showing oneHourTurnaround value true. page 2 is showing the same

Comment: then debug it!! put the debugger on if statement on second page and check why condition is not working ?

Comment: New to debugging. how would I do this on chrome console?

Comment: add 'debugger;' before the if statement of second page and you should open the console screen!! when breakpoint trigger copy the condition of if and put it in the console to check the value

Comment: are you putting single quotes with debugger. just write debugger;

Comment: this is what im writing debugger window.onload = function(){
    //If the body element of the page contains 'one hour turnaround' then trigger an alert
    if(localStorage.getItem('oneHourTurnaround')==true){
      alert("You have a ONE HOUR TURNAROUND order");
    }
 }

Comment: nope write debugger; if(localStorage.getItem('oneHourTurnaround')==true){ alert("You have a ONE HOUR TURNAROUND order"); } }

Comment: just add debugger;  before this statement if(localStorage.getItem('oneHourTurnaround')==true)

Comment: This is what im putting debugger; if(localStorage.getItem('oneHourTurnaround')==true){ alert("You have a ONE HOUR TURNAROUND order"); } }

Comment: i ll upload my file and share link with you later here !!

Comment: check this for debugging help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420/how-do-you-launch-the-javascript-debugger-in-google-chrome/#66431

Comment: If I remove ==true it works. Is there anyway to have this code run every few minutes so the popup is seen in real time?

Comment: yes you can do, on first page or second page ? @M.Heredia

Comment: If it's helpfull, please mark this as a answer and remove the downvote :)

Comment: On the first page. I would like to have it run every few minutes. The phrase 'one hour turnaround' exists there.

Comment: That seems like it just delays the pop up. I want it to keep running/scanning the page as orders marked as 'one hour turnaround' come in to page1

Comment: Got it. Will this also affect page 2? or is there another code for it to show there after the alloted time

Comment: you have to change there also same line as i changed here

Answer (score -1):

Best way is to use Ajax HTTP GET providing URL and searching in response string.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: This is not what the OP asked. The OP asked for how to get the pop up on other pages, not how to read the text of other pages (although, I agree; the title is rather misleading).

Answer (score -1):

`alert` defaults to `window.alert`; the native alert method of the current window the JavaScript is running on.

So, if you want to alert in another window (that you may have opened with `window.open`), you'll have to use that window object:

```
otherWindow.alert(...);
```

Comment: He doesn't want to alert in the other window. He wants to change the `indexOf()` test to look in the innerHTML of the other window.

Comment: `"However, I wanted to show that popup on other pages if the text exists on the original page.

"`

Comment: I interpreted that as the other page contains the Javascript that he showed, and he wants it to check if the text exists on the page that redirected to it.

Comment: @Barmar I can understand that. Honestly, it's just a bad question.