# root element attribute of xml file to be extracted using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

How to get the root element attribute from an XML file URL and pass as a bootstrap table data?

Javascript has to be used to do the above task. 
URl: http://xxxxxx/y.xml

***For example:***

`<xxx-yyyyy zzzzzzz="2016-11-03T06:34:59+02:00">`

*I want to get the date in this root element.*

Please help

Comment: Can you add your XML data too? and what is the expected result of it..

Comment: is it in a external file or already loaded into the DOM? also are you using jquery or only javascript?

Comment: Can you show your complete URL? add the details into the question rather than in comments

Comment: The data is in URL - show us the full URL!

Comment: @sindhu if its confidential then you can remove the confidential data or replace it with some junk characters and provide.. With out the complete information I think its difficult to even start thinking about a solution

Comment: So when you hit that URL you will get a XML data which you need to parse right?

Comment: Exactly. And it seems data is not in url but we need to fetch data from URL  - Am I right?

Comment: That's what even I think..

Comment: @sindhu any chance that you can use Jquery ? or do you require solution in pure javascript?

Comment: @sindhu I gave my answer

Answer (score 1):

- First you need to do a AJAX call to fetch the data from your xml file.
- Second inside your success method you will receive the XML data, you need to parse this data using [$.parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) and then convert it into a jquery object using `$(yourXML)` after that its simple as working on your DOM objects.
- You can read the attribute using the `.attr()` function.

Below is the example code, (here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mVtCD/873/)** which demonstrates working with xml data in jquery)

```
$(function(){  // alternate syntax for $(document).ready(function(){..
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET" ,
      url: "http://xxxxxx/y.xml" ,
      dataType: "xml" ,               // make sure to set the dataType to xml
      success: function(xml) {

        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml); //Parse the givn XML
        var $xml = $(xmlDoc);         // convert XML into jquery object
        var creationDate = $xml.find("ris-metadata").attr('creation');
        alert(creationDate);          // this will give you the required data.

        // this will update the second column data of the first row.
        $('#yourTableId tbody td:eq(1)').text(creationDate); 
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: At what instance do you want to update this data into the table? like on page load? on button click? anything else?

Comment: `$('#yourTableId tr td:eq(1)').text(creationDate )` .. this will add the data into the second column and all the rows.. I can provide exact code if you can share your table structure.. update the question

Comment: So you will have only one row all the time? if not then which row must be update with the date?

Comment: `can json be used for the second column too??` you can update your json with new value and then build the tbody

Comment: add a id to the table and use the code which I have provide.. I have updated my answer

Comment: Great efforts you @Reddy did (y)

Comment: @pedram thanks mate.. My name is Raj too, but I dont belive in god :p

Comment: @sindhu - you should not only mark it as answer - you should also do upvote  ;)

Comment: @Reddy - okay on facebook or so? Coz I don't remember if I have written like "I believe in God" on so.

Comment: @sindhu you need to change that url to what ever you wanted to use. i think thats the issue.. Also check your console window for any errors, Also i have updated my code to wrap it around a `$(function(){...})`

Comment: @sindhu you have to tell me what the error is.. check your developer console window.. you can activate it by pressing F12. and see the tab named `console`

Comment: @Reddy - ohk I got that ;) send me request we will be in touch :)

Comment: @pedram i dont use twitter and Facebook.. I am only on linkedin

Comment: @Reddy - okay I will send connection request.

Comment: @pedram sure thing.

Comment: @sindhu :) did you check your console window??

Comment: @Reddy - can't find you on LinkedIn :(

Comment: @sindhu its not an error from the code I provided.. its saying `myFunction1` is not defined.. you'll have to check it yourself in your code..

Comment: `Unexpected token )` may be there is any extra `)` added while pasting my code.. if you click on the error it will take you to the code and point out the mistake.

Comment: @sindhu yes, unless you have control over the other domain code. I am not sure with other approaches..

Comment: If you dont have control over the domain which you wish to communicate then you cannot do much about it. the other domain must grant you permission to communicate with it..

Comment: @sindhu I didnt get you.

Comment: No, as far as I know.

Comment: @sindhu can you confirm me what the response from the server is.. ie: check what is the value of `xml` variable in success function.

Comment: you can place a debugger and inspect the value. you'll have to use developer window for that here http://stackoverflow.com/a/66431/2592042

Comment: I am not familiar with php but it should be possible, you can fetch that data  in server side and then pass to your page.. So you will change the ajax call to call your server code which in turn will fetch data from that link and give you back. I know this can be done in .Net.. not sure how its done in php..

Comment: btw you didnt tell me the value of `xml` after success

Comment: add this line of code inside your success method `debugger;` now open your developer window and execute the script (in your case reload the page.) the debugger will be hit and you can view the values in the variable. Or simply do a `alert(xml);` which is suitable only in few cases.

Comment: ok so since its a object we cant see it properly in alert.. use the other way I mentioned.

Comment: @sindhu so the response from the URL is not what you have posted in your question. If the response matches to what you have posted in the question this code will work.

Comment: Yes and that is not the response which you said you will get.

Comment: The comment you had put didn't seem to have the same response.

Comment: @Sindhu there are many questions already on stack overflow addressing that issue. Have a check and if those are different from your scenario you can raise a new question. As far as this question is concerned I have given you a answer and if that answer solves the issue posted in this question you can mark it as answer. Have a great day

Comment: Btw if you can use c# then there are libraries which can do this for you.

Comment: There is something called WebClient in c# which is used to fetch data from other websites, https://www.dotnetperls.com/webclient

Comment: @sindhu I am not into php, So I don't know if there exist any methods or not. You can try posting a question about the same.