# angularjs and json server error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- menuFactory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Hi guys I developed small angularjs application and use json server to run my backend code. There is a problem with provider in my code. When I run that I got  errors in below:

> Uncaught TypeError: b.module(...).info is not a function
>       at angular-resource.min.js:6
>       at angular-resource.min.js:14
>   angular.js:12808 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- menuFactory
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.14/$injector/unpr?p0=%24resourceProvider%20%3C-%20%24resource%20%3C-%20menuFactory
>       at http://127.0.0.1:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
>       at http://127.0.0.1:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4381:19
>       at Object.getService [as get] (http://127.0.0.1:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4529:39)
>       at http://127.0.0.1:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4386:45
>       at getService (http://127.0.0.1:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4529:39)
>       at invoke (http://127.0.0.1:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4561:13)
>       at Object.instantiate (http://127.0.0.1:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4578:27)
>       at Object. (http://127.0.0.1:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4438:24)
>       at Object.invoke (http://127.0.0.1:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4570:17)
>       at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (http://127.0.0.1:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4422:37)

Here is my codes for menufactory:

```
angular.module('confusionApp')
    .constant("baseURL","http://localhost:3000/")

        .service('menuFactory', ['$resource','baseURL', function($resource, baseURL) {

            var promotions = [
                {
                          _id:0,
                          name:'Weekend Grand Buffet', 
                          image: 'images/buffet.png',
                          label:'New',
                          price:'19.99',
                          description:'Featuring mouthwatering combinations with a choice of five different salads, six enticing appetizers, six main entrees and five choicest desserts. Free flowing bubbly and soft drinks. All for just $19.99 per person ',
                }

            ];

                this.getDishes = function () {
                  return $resource(baseURL+"dishes/:id",null, {'update': {'method':'PUT'}});
                };


                this.getPromotion = function (index) {

                    return promotions[index];

                };

        }])
```

And this is controller:

```
angular.module('confusionApp')

    .controller('MenuController', ['$scope', 'menuFactory', function($scope, menuFactory) {

        $scope.tab = 1;
        $scope.filtText = '';
        $scope.showDetails = false;
        $scope.showMenu = true;
        $scope.message = "Loading...";
        $scope.dishes = menuFactory.getDishes().query();
        $scope.select = function(setTab) {
            $scope.tab = setTab;

            if (setTab === 2) {
                $scope.filtText = "appetizer";
            }
            else if (setTab === 3) {
                $scope.filtText = "mains";
            }
            else if (setTab === 4) {
                $scope.filtText = "dessert";
            }
            else {
                $scope.filtText = "";
            }
        };

        $scope.isSelected = function (checkTab) {
            return ($scope.tab === checkTab);
        };

        $scope.toggleDetails = function() {
            $scope.showDetails = !$scope.showDetails;
        };
    }])
```

Here is my route:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('confusionApp', ['ui.router', 'ngResource'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider

            // route for the home page
            .state('app', {
                url:'/',
                views: {
                    'header': {
                        templateUrl : 'views/header.html'
                    },
                    'content': {
                        templateUrl : 'views/home.html',
                        controller  : 'IndexController'
                    },
                    'footer': {
                        templateUrl : 'views/footer.html'
                    }
                }

            })

            // route for the aboutus page
            .state('app.aboutus', {
                url:'aboutus',
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl : 'views/aboutus.html',
                        controller  : 'AboutController'                  
                    }
                }
            })

            // route for the contactus page
            .state('app.contactus', {
                url:'contactus',
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl : 'views/contactus.html',
                        controller  : 'ContactController'                  
                    }
                }
            })

            // route for the menu page
            .state('app.menu', {
                url: 'menu',
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl : 'views/menu.html',
                        controller  : 'MenuController'
                    }
                }
            })

            // route for the dishdetail page
            .state('app.dishdetails', {
                url: 'menu/:id',
                views: {
                    'content@': {
                        templateUrl : 'views/dishdetail.html',
                        controller  : 'DishDetailController'
                   }
                }
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    })
;
```

Thank you for reading.

Comment: did you inject the resource module `angular.module('confusionApp', ['ngResource']);`

Comment: Yes this is in another file angular.module('confusionApp', ['ui.router', 'ngResource'])

Comment: Make sure you're calling the factory.js before the controller too

Comment: maybe the file path of resource is wrong. check it is correct file path

Comment: I checked that too. Even manually can access to json file from browser

Comment: You can use Google Chrome development tools to put a break point in the factory and reloading the page thus making sure it it being called and registered

Comment: could you please share any page how to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420/how-do-you-launch-the-javascript-debugger-in-google-chrome    check best 2 answears

Comment: After opening the dev tools there is a sources tab then on the left show navigator open the factory you should see your code and the lines are numbered click to the number and that is a break point then refresh

Comment: Yes I've done. Same as. Thank

Comment: did it work ? what happened

Comment: no the same error again. I don't know why it is like that. I updated file added route that too. Maybe it can help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137761/discussion-between-modar-na-and-agil-yolchuyev).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved issue. The issue is not in my code. I know this is illogical but when I am using angular.js, angular-ui-router.js and angular-resource.js from bower I got the error which is in above. After changing the bower components to CDN it started to work well. So problem related to bower not to my code. Note: I used the same version of angular.js, angular-ui-router.js and angular-resource.js in bower and CDN

Answer (score 0):

Are you defining the controller with a second call to angular.module on same module name ?e

have you tried calling angular.module('name') only once and then build on the returned instance:

var myApp = angular.module('confusionApp')
    .constant("baseURL","http://localhost:3000/") ....

and then:

myApp.controller(...)

if that does not do the trick, please share your root angular.module definition

Comment: The root module definition looks correct. Are you sure that menuFactory service is added before the controller. What the error message is saying is that it cannot find a provider for menuFactory.

Comment: I see but the problem is that I cannot understand why it cannot find

Comment: How are you loading the scripts. In single file or in multi files.  If single file, is the service on top of the controller,  if as multi file, do you load the service before the controller

Comment: Yes this is SPA application. Here is order of the loading:

Comment: <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="../bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
   <script src="../bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/services.js"></script>

Comment: You are loading service.js AFTER controllers.js  try switch them around.

Comment: Switched there place same

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to version gap between angular and ngResource versions. Your angular version (1.4) is too old for the newest version on ngResource (1.6).

If you want to stay with the same angular version, download the angular resource version 1.4.8, or in your bower, put `"angular-resource": "1.5.8"` (without `^` to download the specified version number)

Comment: Thanks for response I solved issue. Yes it was gap between versions