# HTML5 canvas - Images won't draw properly

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have to make a tutorial about horse riding using HTML and CSS. Although I am only a beginner, everything has been going more or less smoothly until I had to draw some images.
As you can see from the code, *Canvas_1* is the biggest canvas and within its borders I have two smaller canvases, *Canvas_2* and *myCanvas*. I need image *preponsko.png* to appear on *myCanvas* and image *dresurno.png* to appear on *Canvas_2*. The images have been scaled to fit the canvas.
When I run the complete code, only the second function, for the image *dresurno.png*, is working and I can see the photo within the canvas borders. The first photo does not appear.
When I delete the second function, first function which draws image *preponsko.png* works and the image appears. This leads me to conclusion that something in the *script* part of the code is wrong, but I just can't figure it out. All help is appreciated.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>  

<HTML>

<!-- background for the whole page -->
<div id="bg">
  <img src="pozadine/pozadina_konji_slajdovi.png" alt="">
</div>

<HEAD>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stil_slajdovi.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stil.css">

<meta charset="UTF-8">

</HEAD>



<BODY>

<!-- Canvas_1 - biggest canvas, within its borders are two smaller canvases, Canvas_2 and myCanvas, are positioned -->
<canvas id="Canvas_1" width="1340" height="618" style="position:absolute; left:10px; top:8px; border:solid red;"></canvas>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="212" height="170" style="position:absolute; left:260px; top:140px; border:3px solid red;"></canvas>
<img id="rsz" width="0" height="0" src="slike/preponsko.png" alt="">

<canvas id="Canvas_2" width="220" height="220" style="position:absolute; left:280px; top:380px; border:3px solid red;"></canvas>
<img id="res_2" width="0" height="0" src="slike/dresurno.png" alt="">

 

<a id="button_nazad" href="d_saddle_information.html" class="action-button shadow animate blue" style="position:absolute; left:171px; top:589px;">Back</a>
<a id="button_naprijed" href="f_saddle_endurance_western.html" class="action-button shadow animate yellow" style="position:absolute; left:1058px; top:589px;">Forward</a>
  

 
 
 
<SCRIPT>
  
 <!-- first function that should draw the "slike/preponsko.png" image  -->
window.onload = function() { 
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");  
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = document.getElementById("rsz");
     
context.drawImage(img, 0,0);
      
}

<!-- second function that should draw the "slike/dresurno.png" image -->
window.onload = function() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas_2");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = document.getElementById("res_2");
     
context.drawImage(img, 0,0);
      
}


</SCRIPT>

</BODY>
```

Comment: I guess it's your homework? Check your dev console.

Comment: Nah, not homework. And unfortunately, as a complete beginner, I have no idea what you just said.

Comment: Ok sorry about that comment then :) [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66434/881032) for help with your dev console

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem is simple to solve.

You have overwritten the `window.onload` function with a second function.

You have

```
window.onload = function(){ ...
```

Then below that you set the same property with a second function

```
window.onload = function(){ // second function
```

`window.onload` can only hold one reference and that will be to the second function.

You can fix it by just defining one function to do everything,

```
window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");  
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img1 = document.getElementById("rsz");         
    context.drawImage(img1, 0,0);

    canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas_2");
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img2 = document.getElementById("res_2");         
    context.drawImage(img2, 0,0);

}
```

or better is to create two render functions and call them from the one onload event

```
// waits for page to load
window.onload = function() {
    renderImage("Canvas_1", "rsz");  // draw first image
    renderImage("Canvas_2", "res_2"); // draw second image
}

// gets a canvas with id = canvasId and draws the image with id = imageId
function renderImage(canvasId, imageId){
    const canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const img = document.getElementById(imageId);         
    ctx.drawimage(img,0,0);
}
```