# jquery icon style is not working for unorder list

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, styles

I have a page that looks like

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul id="menu" style="width:150px">
  <li>
    Bangladesh <span class="ui-icon-caret-1-e"></span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Munshigonj <span class="ui-icon-caret-1-e"></span>
        <ul>
          <li>Khaleast</li>
          <li>Collagepara</li>
          <li>Mathpara</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Dhaka</li>
      <li>Narayangonj</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    USA <span class="ui-icon-caret-1-e"></span>
    <ul>
      <li>Fargo</li>
      <li>New York</li>
      <li>Los Angeles</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    Span <span class="ui-icon-caret-1-e"></span>
    <ul>
      <li>Barcelona</li>
      <li>Real Madrid</li>
      <li>Seviya</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu').menu();
  });
</script>
```

Now the list items are shown as menu but the icon bar for `class="ui-icon-caret-1-e"` or any icon is not showing the icon and the width is not responsive.
What should i do? I tried using a link for style in the head section, But when i hover on the list item with the sapn element it shows a square blank box instead of the icon.

Comment: In the fiddle it's generating ok, I think maybe your default `font-family` is overwriting the  `jquery icon style`. try using `!important` with the `jquery icon font-family`

Comment: i changed the font family still not working

Comment: Can you create a snippet which reproduce the issue? Also, any errors in the `console`?

Comment: I am fairly new in this environment and jquery.don't know how to do what you are asking @mosh

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66434/863110 and https://kb.yoast.com/kb/how-to-find-javascript-errors-with-your-browsers-console/. Also, we need to see the problem it a live. Can you upload your project online?

Comment: In the code snippet it is working but not in my browser. couldn't find out yet what the problem is. online? like where? @MoshFeu

Comment: Also see the snippet now the list item under Bangladesh>Munshigonj. the catet is not in the same line @MoshFeu

Comment: By online I mean, you will eventually upload it to your server and it will have its own domain, right? So if you can upload it to your  server you can add the link so we could see your local environment.

Comment: I am learning now, don't have server or domain

Comment: Got you. Are you using only html files or server files such as .php or .aspx or something. Also, about the falling icon, you can fix it by `#menu .ui-menu-item {white-space: nowrap}`

Comment: yes, i am using .aspx. I don't understand. where should i put these? i tried after the  ('#menu') but it gives me result as plain html not like menu. can you please make an answer. @MoshFeu

Answer (score 0):

To force element to be in the same line, you can use `white-space: nowrap`:

> Collapses whitespace as for normal, but suppresses line breaks (text wrapping) within the source

<sup>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#Values</sup>

Like this:

```css
#menu .ui-menu-item {
  white-space: nowrap
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul id="menu" style="width:150px">
  <li>
    Bangladesh <span class="ui-icon-caret-1-e"></span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Munshigonj <span class="ui-icon-caret-1-e"></span>
        <ul>
          <li>Khaleast</li>
          <li>Collagepara</li>
          <li>Mathpara</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Dhaka</li>
      <li>Narayangonj</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    USA <span class="ui-icon-caret-1-e"></span>
    <ul>
      <li>Fargo</li>
      <li>New York</li>
      <li>Los Angeles</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    Span <span class="ui-icon-caret-1-e"></span>
    <ul>
      <li>Barcelona</li>
      <li>Real Madrid</li>
      <li>Seviya</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu').menu();
  });
</script>
```