# Why Ajax is not populating DIV on 2nd click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tabs

I am loading data from URL inside a TAB `div`, data loads successfully on first request/click but on 2nd request/click it goes to the target link and doesn't populate the target `DIV`.

**Anchor:**

```
<li><a data-toggle="tabAjax" href="http://site.cx/admin/get-coach-stylish-view?userId={{userId}}" id="ajax_tab" class="media_node active span" data-target="#coach-view-stylish-ajax" rel="tooltip">Coach View (Stylised)</a></li>
```

**Div to populate with DATA:**

```
<!-- Coach View Stylised -->
<div id="coach-view-stylish-ajax">
</div>
<!-- Coach View Stylised End -->
```

**JS:**

```
<script>

$('[data-toggle="tabAjax"]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this),
        loadUrl = $this.attr('href'),
        target = $this.attr('data-target');

    $.get(loadUrl, function(data) {
        $(target).html(data);
    });

    $this.tab('show');
    return false;
});

</script>
```

Comment: You could try on method instead of click 
$( document ).on( "click", '[data-toggle="tabAjax"]' , function( event ){
  // your code 
});

Comment: @moshiuramit Thanks I combined the below answer with your suggestion and it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- try to put a debugger in your code, and check that the code is being called on 2nd click. If not, then you need to rebind the click event.

2- You can try this way

```
<li><a data-toggle="tabAjax" href="#" data-href="http://site.cx/admin/get-coach-stylish-view?userId={{userId}}" id="ajax_tab" class="media_node active span" data-target="#coach-view-stylish-ajax" rel="tooltip">Coach View (Stylised)</a></li>
```

make href="#" and store url in data-href="..."

and in your javascript

```
<script>

$('[data-toggle="tabAjax"]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this),
        loadUrl = $this.attr('data-href'), //change href to data-href
        target = $this.attr('data-target');

    $.get(loadUrl, function(data) {
        $(target).html(data);
    });

    $this.tab('show');
    return false;
});

</script>
```

Comment: it blocks going to the target url but it hangs the page and loads nothing now!

Comment: @Imaduddin done?  put debugger inside the click event and debug where it fails.

Comment: yes it worked! How to put debugger can you please elaborate?

Comment: just write debugger; wherever you want to debug. for example <script>
`code`
$('[data-toggle="tabAjax"]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); debugger;
    var $this = $(this),
        loadUrl = $this.attr('data-href'), //change href to data-href
        target = $this.attr('data-target');

    $.get(loadUrl, function(data) { debugger;
        $(target).html(data);
    });

    $this.tab('show');
    return false;
});

</script>`code` and before loading the page, make sure the inspect element console is open. It will hit the debug line.

Comment: have a look at this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420/how-do-you-launch-the-javascript-debugger-in-google-chrome