# how to convert from string to array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

So, I am reading some data with document.getElementById which is already an array.But somehow when I am reading it, it is resulting in a string insted.

I am using the document.getElementById('clients').value, and apparently this returns a string, while I would like to get an array instead.

```
var clients = [];
clients = document.getElementById("clients").value;
alert(clients);
console.log(clients);

for(var i =0; i < clients.length; i++){
    var client = clients[i].toString().split(',');
    alert(client);
}

//console.log(clients) gets:
["[['1'", " 'client1']", " ['2'", " 'client2']", " ['3'", " 'client3']]"]
```

when I am alerting the client from the for loop, I am getting each and every character found in clients one by one. While I would like to get an object to split it. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: post your html too

Comment: It's hard to give a complete answer if you don't tell us what `clients` is.

Comment: split the `clients` directly, no need to loop to split. `clients.split(",")` use `,` to split if this is the character which you want to use as separator

Comment: `document.getElementById which is already an array` --> No, it's an HTML element. Its `.value` isn't an array either, it's a string. Your `for` loop is iterating over every character of the string.

Comment: Please post what `clients` looks like

Comment: clients is not html, its from mongodb

Comment: The `.value` of an HTML element is a string. What do you mean by _"While I would like to get an object to split it."_?

Comment: *"clients is not html, its from mongodb"* so why are you assign a value from a HTML element to the variable called `clients` ?

Comment: @guest271314 I would like to split it as it has other arrays in it

Comment: @jurgen.s "split" is perhaps not the accurate term to use to describe the expected result. Though if you post what the `.value` is at the question, and what the expected result is, it would help resolve the inquiry. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @guest271314 I have something like this: [['1', 'client1'], ['2', 'client2'], ['3', 'client3']] and would like to get: 1 - client1.....

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: _"`//console.log(clients) gets:
["[['1'", " 'client1']", " ['2'", " 'client2']", " ['3'", " 'client3']]"]`"_ How does `console.log(clients)` output an array where the `.value` of an HTML element is a single string? Can you reproduce the output described at the edited question at stacksnippets?

Comment: is it because i am using .split(',') after the .value?

Comment: @jurgen.s Try to inspect the element, copy the `.outerHTML` of the element and place that `.outerHTML` at the question.

Comment: what do you mean by .outerHTML?

Comment: `document.getElementById("clients").outerHTML`, also you are using split after the console.log, so it is impossible that it logs an array. Do you know how to debug using the dev tools? If yes, add a debugger right after `clients = document.getElementById("clients").value;`

Comment: Sorry but no, I do not know how to debug using dev tools

Comment: ok, so, this is the very first thing that every people who is programming need to know... take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420/how-do-you-launch-the-javascript-debugger-in-google-chrome after that, come back here

Comment: mainly I know how to use the inspect (F12), and usually I solve my errors, but I don't know why this one looks so time consuming hahaha

Answer (score 1):

> I have something like this: [['1', 'client1'], ['2', 'client2'], ['3',
>   'client3']] and would like to get: 1 - client1.....

The `.value` should be valid `JSON` or `RegExp` or `String` methods need to be used to convert invalid `JSON` to valid `JSON`. Note the single quotes at HTML attribute surrounding the value and double quotes within the value of the attribute

```
[["1", "client1"], ["2", "client2"], ["3", "client3"]]
```

You can then use `JSON.parse()` to convert `JSON` string to JavaScript object and use `for..of` loop to iterate each element of each nested array.

```js
let value = JSON.parse(clients.value);

for (let [a, b] of value) {
  console.log(a, b)
}
```

```html
<input id="clients" value='[["1", "client1"], ["2", "client2"], ["3", "client3"]]'>
```

Comment: I have tried this but got an error which says: 'Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0'

Comment: @jurgen.s That is because the string returned from `.value` is not valid `JSON`. Can you include the full `.outerHTML` of the element at the question?

Comment: `Unexpected token u` is probably due to a `undefined`. Make sure you retreive the input's value correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to input an array using an `<input>` tag, with values separated by commas or spaces, you have no choice but to use it with `type="text"`, which will return you a string.

You then have to **trim and split** that string to build your array. You can use a regex to split the string on multiple separators:

```js
function getClients() {
  const stringClients = document.getElementById("clients").value;
  const clients = stringClients.trim().split(/[\s,]+/);
  console.log('clients:', clients);
}
```

```html
Enter a comma or space separated list:<br>
<input type="text" id="clients" oninput="getClients()">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("clients").value
```

is a string, not an array. If you do :

```
for(var i =0; i < clients.length; i++)
```

you are actually iterating over every letter of the string, not every word.

What you can do is type `client1,client2,client3` in your input field, then split them this way :

```
const clients = document.getElementById("clients").value.split(",") // ["client1","client2","client3"]
```