# How to make an API call to show data?

Tags: javascript, api

I need to make an API call. The API consists of several arrays containing objects and the objects have 18 keys which I need to display.

How can I just display everything? I have tried doing fetch and ajax calls but none of them seem to work. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks beforehand.

```js
async function events() {
  return $.ajax("/api/address");
  getEvents: function getEvents() {
    return $.ajax("/api/address");
  };
  targetMarket: function targetMarket(id, events) {
    return events.filter(function(event) {
      return event.eventID === id;
    });
  };
  eventsName: function eventsName(events, name) {
    return events.filter(function(event) {
      return events.event.eventID === events.eventID;
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: Hmm maybe first thing you'd want to do is not use jquery ajax but angular's `HttpClient`?

Comment: Is this [tag:angular] because the code does not look like it at all. Start by creating an [mcve] with a clear description of what is not working. If this *is* actually [tag:angular] then start with the documentation and tutorials on the https://angular.io site, they are excellent.

Comment: It could potentially be internal to AngularJS- but I agree, Angular tag should be removed.

Comment: Please format your code, it is very hard to read

Comment: sorry, there is no Angular and I am also a newbie developer. I am trying to understand how to make an API call and show data ( ajax call of the data being logged).

Comment: How are you calling this function/object?

Answer (score 0):

API calls can look a little intimidating starting off, keep at it!

Here's an example of getting simple data using an Ajax call to an API. This is in plain JavaScript, no libraries needed:

```
let cryptoData;

function ajaxGet(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', url);
    req.onload = function() {
      if (req.status === 200) {
        resolve(req.response);
        cryptoData = JSON.parse(req.response); // the API response with the data is here (req.response). We use the JSON.parse() method to convert req.response string into a JSON object, since it originally comes in as a string.
        showAjaxData();
      } else {
        reject(Error(req.statusText));
      }
    };
    req.onerror = function(err) {
      reject(Error("Looks like we've got an error..."));
    };
    req.send();
  });
}


function showAjaxData() {
  console.log(cryptoData[0]);
}

ajaxGet(`https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/`);
```

You can see the code in action at this [JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/samlegros/9wk8a0r2/). Just remember to [open the browser console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420/how-do-you-launch-the-javascript-debugger-in-google-chrome) to view the logged API data.

Feel free to check out this [w3schools tutorial on Ajax calls](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much Sam, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I forgot to add, `console.log(cryptoData[0]);` will display the entire JSON object. If you want to view/ save each item, simply use the [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) such as `console.log(cryptoData[0].name);`, and this will return "Bitcoin" as a string. You can do this for all the data points you like!