# JavaScript file does not execute withing HTML

Tags: javascript, html

My JavaScript is supposed to add elements from an array to a table with each iteration of for loop.
However, when I load my HTML page into FireFox, nothing of the sort happens. The table just stays the way I have created it in HTML. What can be the issue here? The code that I inserted into the JavaScript can be found at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Classic Swedish Pancakes Recipe</title>
        <link href="HW5Part1.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Classic Swedish Pancakes</h1>

            <table id = "myTable" class="ingredients">
                <tr>
                    <th>Ingredient</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                </tr>


            </table>
            <script>
                    //Creating an array with ingredient (ingredient followed by its quantity
                    var ingredients = new Array(‘separated eggs’, '3', 
                                                'whole milk', '1 cup', 
                                                'melted unsalted butter', '4 Tbsp.', 
                                                'sugar', '2 Tbsp.', 
                                                'vanilla extract', '1 tsp.', 
                                                'table salt', '1/4 tsp.', 
                                                'all-purpose flour', '1 cup', 
                                                'butter', '2 tsp.');


                    //Assigning a variable to our table
                    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
                    //Creating a for loop with 8 iterations
                        for (var i = 0; i <8; i++) {
                            var row = table.insertRow(i+1);
                            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                            cell1.outerHTML = ingredients.item(i*2);
                            cell2.outerHTML = ingredients.item(i*2+1);}
            </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I dunno about you, but I don't think `‘separated eggs’` looks right.

Comment: `ingredients.item(i*2)`, You don't access arrays elements like this, use `[]` instead

Comment: Always check the [error console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420/how-do-you-launch-the-javascript-debugger-in-google-chrome) . Start there and fix the multitude of syntax errors there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `item` is not defined.

What you need is arrays within the `ingredients` array, as so:

```
var ingredients = [
    ['separated eggs', '3'],
    ['whole milk', '1 cup'],
    ['melted unsalted butter', '4 Tbsp.'],
    ['sugar', '2 Tbsp.'],
    ['vanilla extract', '1 tsp.'],
    ['table salt', '1/4 tsp.'],
    ['all-purpose flour', '1 cup'],
    ['butter', '2 tsp.']
];
```

From there, you can create your loop to access each item individually.

In it, you first need to grab `i`, followed by `0` or `1`. `0` for the ingredient and `1` for the quantity.

```
ingredients[i][0]
```

```js
//Creating an array with ingredient (ingredient followed by its quantity
var ingredients = [
    ['separated eggs', '3'],
    ['whole milk', '1 cup'],
    ['melted unsalted butter', '4 Tbsp.'],
    ['sugar', '2 Tbsp.'],
    ['vanilla extract', '1 tsp.'],
    ['table salt', '1/4 tsp.'],
    ['all-purpose flour', '1 cup'],
    ['butter', '2 tsp.']
];


//Assigning a variable to our table
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
//Creating a for loop with 8 iterations
for (var i = 0; i < ingredients.length; i++) {
    var row = table.insertRow(i + 1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = ingredients[i][0];
    cell2.innerHTML = ingredients[i][1];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Classic Swedish Pancakes Recipe</title>
        <link href="HW5Part1.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Classic Swedish Pancakes</h1>

            <table id="myTable" class="ingredients">
                <tr>
                    <th>Ingredient</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                </tr>


            </table>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Please note that the quotes surrounding `seperated eggs` are special characters and will break your code.

Comment: Your solution works. Thank you very much! As for the ".item". It was mentioned as one of the methods for retrieving elements from an array by my textbook. I guess it is wrong.

Comment: Better to use `ingredients.length` in the loop initialization, instead of hard coding 8.

Comment: @JonP True. Just fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

Well you have some issues.

The "seperated eggs" doesnt look like a valid string. I'd double check on that.

Also ".item" is not a valid function for an array. Just use the index:

```
cell1.outerHTML = ingredients[(i*2)];
```

Comment: I have fixed "separated eggs" string and tried to use your index. However, it still does not work. ".item" is a valid function for an array according to the text I am using.  The text is "JAVASCRIPT & JQUERY 
Interactive Front-End Web Development "
by John Duckett

Comment: @Dante `.item` comes from jQuery. You have **not** included jQuery based on the code you have given us, and until this comment you have given us no indication that you are using jQuery.

Comment: @Jon P My textbook did not mention that  ".item" was jQuery and not JavaScript or I got something confused, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the apostrophes you used around 'separated eggs' are some special character and not being read by my text editor.  Change those to some regular ' characers.

Next, I got an error that igredients.item is not a function.  I'd never heard of that before either.  Just change it to ingredients[i*2].  See the code below:

```
var ingredients = new Array('separated eggs', '3',
                            'whole milk', '1 cup',
                            'melted unsalted butter',Tbsp.',
                            'sugar', '2 Tbsp.',
                            'vanilla extract', '1 tsp.',
                            'table salt', '1/4 tsp.',
                            'all-purpose flour', '1 cup',
                            'butter', '2 tsp.');

var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

for (var i = 0; i <8; i++) {
    var row = table.insertRow(i+1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = ingredients[i*2];
    cell2.innerHTML = ingredients[i*2+1];
}
```

Also, just as a tip, you can write your array much nicer like this:

```
   var ingredients = [
      'separated eggs', '3',
      'whole milk', '1 cup',
      'melted unsalted butter',Tbsp.',
      'sugar', '2 Tbsp.',
      'vanilla extract', '1 tsp.',
      'table salt', '1/4 tsp.',
      'all-purpose flour', '1 cup',
      'butter', '2 tsp.'
   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to expand on [Michelles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58193062/4665) great answer and modernize it a little.

I'm going to replace the array of array with a more meaningful array of objects. Then I'll use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for the content.

Finally We'll only update the DOM once as each DOM update causes a redraw, which can get expensive.

```js
//Creating an array with ingredient (ingredient followed by its quantity
var ingredients = [
  {ingredient:'separated eggs', amount:'3'},
  {ingredient:'whole milk', amount: '1 cup'},
  {ingredient:'melted unsalted butter', amount: '4 Tbsp.'},
  {ingredient:'sugar', amount: '2 Tbsp.'},
  {ingredient:'vanilla extract', amount: '1 tsp.'},
  {ingredient:'table salt', amount: '1/4 tsp.'},
  {ingredient:'all-purpose flour', amount: '1 cup'},
  {ingredient:'butter', amount: '2 tsp.'}
];


//Assigning a variable to our table
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var newHTML = "";

//iterate the array
ingredients.forEach(function(item){
  newHTML += `
<tr>
   <td>${item.ingredient}</td>
   <td>${item.amount}</td>
</tr>`
});
//finally update the table
table.innerHTML += newHTML;
```

```html
<h1>Classic Swedish Pancakes</h1>

<table id="myTable" class="ingredients">
  <tr>
    <th>Ingredient</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
  </tr>
```

Comment: I do realize that using for loop is not necessary, that was just directions for my assignment to practice for loop in JavaScript.