# Debugging JavaScript in Blade file - Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, phpstorm, xdebug, laravel-blade

First of all, I want to mention I use **Laravel 5.8** and **PhpStorm 2019.2.3**. I am using **Xdebug** for debugging.

It's common to debug PHP code written in Blade file. Is there any phpstorm extension which can debug JavaScript code under `script` tag written in blade file.

I google it but couldn't find an answer either is it possible or not.

Comment: Xdebug is for PHP code, not JavaScript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you launch the JavaScript debugger in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66420/how-do-you-launch-the-javascript-debugger-in-google-chrome)